# Validation errors are not output and fields with previous Form data are not returned

Tags: validation, laravel-5

Laravel 5.2

**view** where the form of sending data (**'blade'**):

```
@if( count($errors) > 0 )
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <ul>
                @foreach( $errors->all() as $error ) <li>{{ $error }}</li> @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    @endif

    <form method="POST" action="{{  route('contact') }}">  <!-- <?//='/contact');?> Or <?//=route('contact');?> -->
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" placeholder="Enter Name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email address:</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" placeholder="Enter E-mail">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="site">Site:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="site" name="site" value="{{ old('site') }}" placeholder="Enter Site">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="text_area">Text:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="text_area" name="text_area" rows="3" placeholder="Some text....."> {{ old('text_area') }} </textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>

    </div> <!--/class="col-"-->
</div> <!--/class="row"-->
```

**ContactController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class ContactController extends Controller {


    public function show( Request $request, $prm=false ){

        $my_array = ['title1'=>'This variable `$title1` content', 'title2'=>'This variable `$title2` content', 'title3'=>'This variable `$title3` content']; //массив
        $my_array2 = ['one'=>array('param1'=>'This variable `param1` content', 'param2'=>'This variable `param2` content', 'param3'=>'This variable `param3` content'),
            'two'=>array('param4'=>'This variabl e `param4` content', 'param5'=>'This variable `param5` content', 'param6'=>'This variable `param6` content')
        ];

        $my_array3 = array(
            'title'=>'Contact',
            'data'=>[ 'one'=>'list 1',
                'two'=>'list 2',
                'three'=>'list 3',
                'four'=>'list 4',
                'five'=>'list 5',
            ],
            'dataI'=>['list-1','list-2','list-3','list-4','list-6','list-6'],
            'bvar'=>true,
            'script'=>"<script>alert('Hello! ++')</script>"
        );

        /** VALIDATION on Request */
        if( $request->isMethod('post') ) {

            $rules = [
                'name' => 'required|max:10',
                'email' => 'required|email',
                //'site'=>'required',
                //'text_area'=>'required',
            ];

            $messages = [
                'required' => 'The :attribute field is required.',
            ];

            $this->validate($request, $rules, $messages);
                dump( $request->all() );
                dump( $request->session()->all() );
        }


        if( view()->exists('default.contact') ){
            return view('default.contact')
                ->withMydata($my_array2)
                ->withMydata2($my_array)
                ->withMydata3($my_array3);
        }
        else { abort(404); }

    }

}
```

**`/app/Http/Kernel.php`**

```
   /**
 * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
 *
 * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
];
```

How can I see that validation fulfills and its rules are in effect,
But I do not see the display of validation errors when it is not passed and the data in the input fields when the Form is filled when redirecting back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me show you my method which also uses validation on Laravel 5.2 and find out what the difference you have with this code:

The Controller which handles the request:

```
$validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'data1' => 'required',
        'data2' => 'required|in:bla1,bla2,bla3',
        'data3' => 'required|array',
        'data3.*' => 'required|json',
        'data4' => 'required_if:data2,bla2',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $request->flash();
        return \Response::make(\View::make('theform')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput($request->all())
            ->render()
        , 406);
    }
```

The form which contains the form which has been submitted and redrawn with error logs, named 'theform':

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="trip_name" id="trip_name" 
    placeholder="Gezi ismi" value="{{ old('trip_name') }}">
@if ($errors->has('trip_name'))
    <span class="help-block">
        <strong>{{ $errors->first('trip_name') }}</strong>
    </span>
@endif
```

This is one way to show it. You can also view it your way as:

```
@if( count($errors) > 0 )
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach( $errors->all() as $error ) 
                <li>{{ $error }}</li> 
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem did not stop there ))

I create the validation through my own class `Request` and divide routes for GET and POST and defined separate methods for them in my Controller.

**1.** *app/Http/routes.php*

```
Route::get('/contact_form/{prm?}', ['uses'=>'Admin\ContactformController@show_form_get'])->name('contact_form');

Route::post('/contact_form', ['uses'=>'Admin\ContactformController@show_form_post']);
```

**2.** *app/Http/Requests/ContactRequest.php* - my custom Request class with validation rules:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class ContactRequest extends Request
{

    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;  //false
    }


    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|max:10',
            //'name' => 'exists:users,name',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'site'=>'required',
        ];
    }

}  //__/class ContactRequest
```

**3.** *app/Http/Requests/ContactRequest.php* - my Controller with POST and GET handling:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Requests\ContactRequest; //custom Request class with validation rules
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class ContactformController extends Controller {

    public $show_controller_method = array(__METHOD__);


    /** Method handler http-request with GET
    */
    public function show_form_get( ){

        $this->show_controller_method[] = 'showform()';
        if( view()->exists('default.contact_form') ){
            return view('default.contact_form')->withInfoMethodController($this->show_controller_method);
        }
        else { abort(404); }

    }  //__/public function show_form_get()


    /** Method handler http-request with POST
    */
    public function show_form_post( ContactRequest $request ){

        if( $request->isMethod('post') ):
            dump( $request->all() );
        endif;
    }
```

**3.** The view remained the same and there is a return of data "old inputs":

```
value="{{ old('name') }}"  value="{{ old('email') }}"   and so on...
```

and errors of validation if they exist:

```
@if( count($errors) > 0 )
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach( $errors->all() as $error ) <li>{{ $error }}</li> @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

- Now the validation works (if it passes successfully - I see a dump() the POST.

  - If the validation falls, then a redirect occurs, but there are no validation errors and there are no old inputs.

Tell me please what I'm doing is not right?